# Pass data on parent change angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I have two dropdown list and I need to pass both of their values to updateGraph function in the component when either one of the two changes

```
   <div class="card-body" (change)="updateGraph($event)">
                        <div class="row">
                            <label>City</label>
                            <select data-id="selects1" class="browser-default custom-select">
                                <label>City</label>
                                <option selected>Select a city</option>
                                <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city">{{ city }} </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label>Scale</label>
                            <select data-id="selects" class="browser-default custom-select">
                                <option selected>Scale</option>
                                <option *ngFor="let scale of scales" [ngValue]="scale.value">{{ scale.Name }}
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <mdb-date-picker name="mydate" [options]="myDatePickerOptions" [placeholder]="'Selected date'"
                                [(ngModel)]="model" required></mdb-date-picker>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply to updateGraph on both select elements like below

```
<select data-id="selects1" (change)="updateGraph($event.target.value)"> class="browser-default custom-select">
                                <label>City</label>
                                <option selected>Select a city</option>
                                <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city">{{ city }} </option>
                            </select>
```

If you want to bind a property like id as value

```
<option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city.id">
```

So **$event.target.value** will be the selected **id**

if you want to reuse the same method for both dropdown , just pass some constantvalue as  a parameter

```
 updateGraph('scale',$event.target.value)  //for scale 
 updateGraph('city',$event.target.value) //city
```

from the component  you can check a condition

```
updateGraph(type,value){
if(type==='scale'){
  //value for scale 
}
else if(type==='city'){
//value for city
}
}
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dropdown-binding?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I understand the concept and it works like this but the updateGraph function its making a call to a service and the service is calling up an API but this API needs to receive two parameters. ok lets say that I have already selected a city but now i go and i select an scale from here I can get the scale value, but how do i get the city that i previously selected on that event?

Comment: @ChristianBawman you can create a separate property for holding the selectedValue for both city and scale in the component like in the stackblitz demo. So the value of the property will be always there. If you are not clear the idea I can update the stackblitz by adding one more dropdown

Comment: @ChristianBawman Updated the demo application. Please let me know if you have any question

Comment: just AMAZING, it worked. I'm not using a button, instead i'm calling directly the function updateGraph and with a few validations I was able to get the values in that function, thank you very so much sir !

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with

```
(change)="updateGraph($event)"
```

being placed on a div element, as divs do not have onChange events, unless the card-body is somehow providing that.

I would move that call to both of the select elements, so it will be triggered on either of the select's onChange events.

You can also pass in whatever variable you need to, or just reference them from the .ts file.

Option #1 looks like it would be, moving it to the selects and then using:

```
(change)="updateGraph(city, scale.Name)"
```

Option #2 on the .ts file you could just reference `this.city` and `this.scale.Name` in your `updateGraph` function.

**But make sure the (change) is on both of the select elements**

Comment: I don't have nothing called 'state' actually on my code and well the scale I do have it but when I do a console log in the function it says that cannot read the property Name.

Comment: sorry i meant city!

Comment: PS.  unless you're planning on using $event you dont have to use it.  but you can use it if you do not have access to the binded model.  hope that makes sense